# Wrote a code to have random photos shown but need to show only four img at a given time

Tags: php, css, html

So I have a code that is responsive in nature that **is supposed to** places four (4) photos side by side and shows the photos at random order.

However, because I am just starting out I don't know how to create a code that makes sure there are only four (4) photos shown at any given time???

So based on my code provided below how do I only show four photos at a time. (Even though I want there to be at least eight (8) possible photos that it sorts through.)

CODE USED:

```
<br>
<br>
<h50><?php echo $this->translate('Be Discovered!'); ?></h50>
and connected. Meet anyone & see everything!</a></p>
<br>

<?php

$pics = [
    "/public/admin/haleyfoxforabout333.jpg",
    "/public/admin/haleyfoxforabout333.jpg",
    "/public/admin/team5aboutG333.jpg",
    "/public/admin/team6about333.jpg",
    "https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/team1.jpg",
    "https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/team2.jpg",
    "https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/team3.jpg",
    "/public/admin/team4_333.jpg"
];

shuffle($pics);
?>

<style>

    h50 {
        padding: 0 30px 8px;
        width: auto;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D2DBE8;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .headerz {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 32px;
    }

    .rowz {
        display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 0 4px;
    }

    /* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
    .columnz {
        -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
        flex: 25%;
        max-width: 25%;
        padding: 0 4px;
    }

    .columnz img {
        margin-top: 8px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    /* RL - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        .columnz {
            -ms-flex: 50%;
            flex: 50%;
            max-width: 50%;
        }
    }

    /* RL Takes the two columns stack on top of each other. */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .columnz {
            -ms-flex: 100%;
            flex: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    }

</style>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="rowz">
    <?php
    foreach ($pics as $pic) {
        echo '<div class="columnz">';
        echo '<img src="' . $pic . '" style="width:100%">';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_rand`, it will give your random **keys** from your array. Second argument defines how many keys do you want:

```
$keys = array_rand($pics, 4);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $pics[$key];
}
```

Or you can **slice** you shuffled array:

```
shuffle($pics);
$pics = array_slice($pics, 0, 4); // reduces your array to 4 elements
```

Or you can use a counter and `break` foreach:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($pics as $pic){
    if ($counter == 4) {
        break;
    }

    echo $pic;
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: @AnthonySosa @u_mulder Only the second and third option (as long as the array is shuffled) guarantee uniqueness, right? It is my understanding that `array_rand` can return duplicated elements.

Comment: @u_mulder The code works great. A side question is there any code that makes sure the same photo isn't shown twice. Example of the four photos two of them are the exact same photo? But I don't want that to happen.

Comment: @msgI ask the same question I am currently using option 2 and it is creating duplicates.

Comment: @AnthonySosa in your case might be because you have duplicates in your array to begin with (first and second).

Comment: @msg Thanks missed that.